# Contact form email template

Tags: theming, 8, emails

Currently, the whole email generated by the Contact module is without a single line break. They look very ugly. Is there a way to edit the email template for specific contact forms?

Comment: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/196168/change-default-email-sent-using-the-contact-forms-drupal-8#comments-196168

Comment: I cannot edit the email template for contact forms. There are many others, but only for user management tasks (such as registration, deletion...)

Comment: Two possibilities for D8 to send HTML email via a contact form though I have not tried either: https://www.drupal.org/project/mailsystem and https://www.drupal.org/project/mimemail

Answer (score 1):

If you check core.services.yml you can see the service which sends mail (*plugin.manager.mail*).  It looks for  overrides for default mail plugin starting from message_id to module name. You can create simple new mail plugin which sends HTML mail and set this in configuration "system.mail".

```
 drush cset system.mail interface.contact your_mail_plugin  // this will change mail plugin for contact module
```

Creating a mail plugin is easy and you can find example here *Drupal\Core\Mail\Plugin\Mail*

MailSystem  module does this and it supports advanced options https://www.drupal.org/project/mailsystem